# Manual object mapping in ado.net entity

Tags: c#, ado.net, entity

I writing data access layer using ado.net entity. But I want do it by manual (not generate code by tool).

I need help how to do it, how many step and example.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at Entity Framework Code First. See [EF 4.1 Code First Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx)